# Not being able to clearInterval

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer, clearinterval

I'm new one here and in Javascript too.
I was creating a timer which will display how many days, hours, minutes, seconds are left from a particular date and time.
I was successful in programming this but here is a problem which I'm not able to resolve.
When the particular date and time is reached the timer shows 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds left. But just after that the values go negative. I don't want to show negative values that's why I used clearInterval to stop updating the DOM per second but its not working. Here's my code...

```js
function init()
{
.
.
.
var timeCalc = setInterval(timeRemainingCalc, 1000);
}
    
    var launchTime = new Date("05/28/2015 00:56:00").getTime(); //here goes a particular date and time
    
    function timeRemainingCalc() {
        var currentTime = new Date(); //this gets client's date and time
        var daysleft = Math.floor(((launchTime - currentTime.getTime()) / 1000) / 86400);
        var hoursleft = Math.floor(((launchTime - currentTime.getTime()) / 1000) / 3600) - daysleft * 24;
        var minutesleft = Math.floor(((launchTime - currentTime.getTime()) / 1000) / 60) - daysleft * 24 * 60 - hoursleft * 60;
        var secondsleft = Math.floor((launchTime - currentTime.getTime()) / 1000) - daysleft * 24 * 60 * 60 - hoursleft * 60 * 60 - minutesleft * 60;
        if (daysleft <= 0 && hoursleft <= 0 && minutesleft <= 0 && secondsleft <= 0) //checks if the particular time has already been reached or not? i.e. negative value
        {
            clearInterval(timeCalc); //this one is not working...
        } else //code inside this only updates 1st and 2nd digit of days, hours, etc of the timer
        {
            document.getElementById('Days0').innerHTML = Math.floor(daysleft / 10);
            document.getElementById('Days1').innerHTML = daysleft - Math.floor(daysleft / 10) * 10;
            document.getElementById('Hours0').innerHTML = Math.floor(hoursleft / 10);
            document.getElementById('Hours1').innerHTML = hoursleft - Math.floor(hoursleft / 10) * 10;
            document.getElementById('Minutes0').innerHTML = Math.floor(minutesleft / 10);
            document.getElementById('Minutes1').innerHTML = minutesleft - Math.floor(minutesleft / 10) * 10;
            document.getElementById('Seconds0').innerHTML = Math.floor(secondsleft / 10);
            document.getElementById('Seconds1').innerHTML = secondsleft - Math.floor(secondsleft / 10) * 10;
        }
    }
```

I think the HTML code and CSS code is unnecessary here. If required then tell me I'll upload them too.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd prefer `launchTime <= currentTime.getTime()` instead of `daysleft <= 0 && hoursleft <= 0 && minutesleft <= 0 && secondsleft <= 0`.

Comment: I think you never hit your if, because not all values go negative, just the days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining timecalc in an other function scope. You can't access the variable.

Easiest solution: Do a

```
var timeCalc;
function init()
{    ...
     timeCalc = setInterval(timeRemainingCalc, 1000);
}
```

to have timeCalc globally available.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code never calls `clearInterval` unless the time is exactly the `launchTime`.

Fiddle with the this modified version's `launchTime` value and you'll see:

```
var timeCalc = setInterval(timeRemainingCalc, 1000);

var launchTime = new Date("01/01/2015 00:01:00").getTime(); //here goes a particular date and time

function timeRemainingCalc() {
    var currentTime = new Date(); //this gets client's date and time
    var daysleft = Math.floor(((launchTime - currentTime.getTime()) / 1000) / 86400);
    var hoursleft = Math.floor(((launchTime - currentTime.getTime()) / 1000) / 3600) - daysleft * 24;
    var minutesleft = Math.floor(((launchTime - currentTime.getTime()) / 1000) / 60) - daysleft * 24 * 60 - hoursleft * 60;
    var secondsleft = Math.floor((launchTime - currentTime.getTime()) / 1000) - daysleft * 24 * 60 * 60 - hoursleft * 60 * 60 - minutesleft * 60;

    if (daysleft <= 0 && hoursleft <= 0 && minutesleft <= 0 && secondsleft <= 0) //checks if the particular time has already been reached or not? i.e. negative value
    {
        console.log("Clear!");
        clearInterval(timeCalc); //this one is not working...
    } else //code inside this only updates 1st and 2nd digit of days, hours, etc of the timer
    {
        console.log("daysleft: " + daysleft);
        console.log("hoursleft: " + hoursleft);
        console.log("minutesleft: " + minutesleft);
        console.log("secondsleft: " + secondsleft);
        console.log("");
    }
}
```

jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/o991pkxa/

You should be checking if *any* of the `days/hours/minutes/secondsleft` variables are negative, not if *all* of them are.